# Optimising a SQL Query where multiple left join duplicated twice

Tags: mysql

If someone could offer advice on improving the below query this would be most useful. I am unsure how I can make improvement when i have a left join twice in many instance to seperate tables. For example I have a location left join to the user table and a location left join to the image gallery table. I was unsure if i could optimise the sql from this point of view. It is very slow at the moment. I have ensured all columns are indexed on all joins and where statements.

```
SELECT im.alias_title, im.title,im.guid_id, im.description, im.hits, im.show_comment, im.can_print,
 im.can_download, im.can_share, im.created_on, im.date_taken, im.approved, im.visible,
ad.address_line_1, ad.address_line_2, ad.town_village_city, ad.state_province_county, ad.postal_code, ad.other_address_detail, co.country,
geo.latitude, geo.longitude, geo.zoom, geo.yaw, geo.pitch,
c.make, c.model,
us.first_name, us.surname, uf.user_id, uf.real_name, uf.user_name, uf.gender, uf.description, uf.description, uf.buddy_icon_url, uf.first_taken_date, uf.first_date,
uf.time_zone_label, uf.time_zone_offset,
adf.address_line_1 as user_address_line_1, adf.address_line_2 as user_address_line_2, adf.town_village_city as user_town_village_city, adf.state_province_county as user_state_province_county, 
adf.postal_code as user_postal_code, adf.other_address_detail as user_other_address_detail, cof.country as user_country,
geof.latitude as user_geolocation_latitude, geof.longitude as user_geolocation_longitude, geof.zoom as user_geolocation_zoom, geof.yaw as user_geolocation_yaw, geof.pitch as user_geolocation_pitch,
im.alias_title = in_image_alias_title AS image_selected -- image selected
FROM image im
LEFT JOIN address ad ON im.address_id = ad.id
LEFT JOIN country co ON ad.country_id = co.id
LEFT JOIN geolocation geo ON im.geolocation_id = geo.id
LEFT JOIN camera c ON im.camera_id = c.id
INNER JOIN user us ON im.user_id = us.id
LEFT JOIN user_flickr uf ON us.id = uf.id
LEFT JOIN address adf ON uf.address_id =adf.id
LEFT JOIN country cof ON ad.country_id = cof.id
LEFT JOIN geolocation geof ON uf.geolocation_id = geof.id
WHERE (im.alias_title = in_image_alias_title OR im.user_id = user_id)
AND im.approved = in_image_approved 
AND im.visible = in_image_visible
AND (im.advertise_to <= NOW() OR im.advertise_to IS NULL)
ORDER BY image_selected DESC;
```

[image]

Comment: OK, do you *really* need all those columns from all those tables?

Comment: yep need them on the image page.

Comment: Run an EXPLAIN on the query.

Comment: How long is it taking to execute?  What kind of performance is acceptable?

Comment: taking 3 seconds on average- need it down to around a second to be honest

Comment: How many rows in the largest table?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22423/discussion-between-matthew-chambers-and-robert-harvey)

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions.**  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the discussion / chat room, and learning more of what you were trying to do...

Build a compound index on the components associated with your where clause so all parts can be applied, not just the best of the first key element.  Also, by removing the "alias_title" from the where clause (since you were getting the user ID based on the alias title to begin with), it was a redundant clause taking up more consideration in the query.

I would index on  (user_id, approved, visible, advertise_to )

The results will come back and be small in the scheme of things, so your ultimate "order by" clause will have no problem with its final sort output.